# PHP how to iterate over hierarhical flat array?

Tags: php, algorithm

I have this data set, which is a flat hierarhical multi-dimensional array:

```
[
    [
        'title' => 'Skylake',
        'type' => 'category',
        'items' => 
        [
            [
                'title' => 'Core i3',
                'type' => 'category',
                'items' => 
                [
                    [
                        'title' => '6100',
                        'type' => 'product',
                        'price' => 100.0,
                    ],
                    [
                        'title' => '6300',
                        'type' => 'product',
                        'price' => 110.0,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Core i7',
                'type' => 'category',
                'items' => [
                    [
                        'title' => '7700',
                        'type' => 'product',
                        'price' => 330.0,
                    ],
                    [
                        'title' => '7700K',
                        'type' => 'product',
                        'price' => 370.0,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'KabyLake',
        'type' => 'category',
    ]
];
```

As you can see there are two main category: Skylake and Kabylake, and these contains other subcategories and subcategories contain products.

I have tried to iterate over this flat array, but something went wrong, because the 'core i7' category will not know that its parent is 'Skylake'.
When I insert the data into the database its parent_id will be null.

```
   /**
     * Creates catalog.
     * @param mixin $sampleItems sample items
     * @param interger $categoryId id of category (parent id)
     */
    private function createCatalog(&$sampleItems, $categoryId = null)
    {
        foreach ($sampleItems as $sampleItem) {
            if ($sampleItem['type'] == 'category') {
                $categoryId = $this->createCategory($sampleItem, $categoryId);
            } else {
                $this->createProduct($sampleItem, $categoryId);
            }
            $hasItems = isset($sampleItem['items']) && is_array($sampleItem['items']);
            if ($hasItems) {
                $this->createCatalog($sampleItem['items'], $categoryId);
                $categoryId = null;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create category.
     * @param mixin $sampleData
     * @param integer $parentId ID of parent category
     * @return integer ID of created category
     */
    private function createCategory($sampleData, $parentId)
    {
        $category = new Category();
        if ($parentId !== null) {
            $category->parent_id = $parentId;
        }
        $category->title = $sampleData['title'];
        $category->status = 1;
        $category->save();

        return $category->id;
    }

    /**
     * Create Product.
     * @param mixin $sampleData
     * @param integer $categoryId
     */
    private function createProduct($sampleData, $categoryId)
    {
        $product = new Product();
        if ($categoryId !== null) {
            $product->category_id = $categoryId;
        }
        $product->title = $sampleData['title'];
        $product->price = $sampleData['price'];
        $product->description = $sampleData['description'];
        $product->status = 1;
        $product->save();
    }
```

Unfortunately this is the current hierarchy in the database:

```
Skylake
  Core i3
Core i7
KabyLake
```

The Core i7 should be under the Skylake.

I think the problem is that $parentId will null for Core i7.

But I do not see why.

Comment: I disagree with your terminology. "Flat" and "hierarchical" are mutually-exclusive. What you have is a graph of associative-arrays - not "flat" at all.

Comment: How many levels-deep can categories go? If a category can contain a category that contains another category (and so on) then you will need to use a graph-traversal algorithm, such a recursive function or use a stack for BFS or DFS traversal.

Comment: @Dai looks like `createCatalog` is recursive.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Ah, eagle eyes! I didn't see that at first-glance.

Comment: @Dai you are right, now I learnt the correct English word to describe this problem :). I totally forget how it is called. I searched on Google with (flat, hierarchical words). My native langauge is not part of indo-german language family. So sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the same variable `$categoryId` for the parent of the current category and for the parents of the sub-categories that you're creating in the loop. When you do `$categoryId = null;` after creating a nested catalog, that affects the next call to `createCategory()`.

Use a different variable, I use `$subcat` below.

```
private function createCatalog(&$sampleItems, $categoryId = null)
{
    $subcat = null;
    foreach ($sampleItems as $sampleItem) {
        if ($sampleItem['type'] == 'category') {
            $subcat = $this->createCategory($sampleItem, $categoryId);
        } else {
            $this->createProduct($sampleItem, $categoryId);
        }
        $hasItems = isset($sampleItem['items']) && is_array($sampleItem['items']);
        if ($hasItems) {
            $this->createCatalog($sampleItem['items'], $subcat);
            $subcat = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean it will affect the next call to `createCatalog`?

Comment: No, I mean the next `$categoryId = $this->createCategory($sampleItem, $categoryId);`